# How to get more sample Tiny Purity Tablets?

Tags: fiz

I failed to meet Z's conditions using the tablets she gave me. How can I get more without completing A Lesson in Modifiers, or do I need to restart?

Answer (score 3):

[image: Tiny Purity Tablet under the Ingredients tab]

After filling your recipe, head to the Ingredients tab. Ingredients are colour coded, with malts having a yellow background, hops having a green background, etc. At the bottom of the list will be the ingredients with an orange background, including recipe modifiers. You can purchase as many tiny purity tablets as you want for 100 coins each.

Answer (score 0):

They should be available to buy from the list of ingredients I believe.